# Can I use 2 modes of I2C operation together in 1 code? For STM32F407 interfaced with MPU6050 sensor

Tags: stm32, i2c, arm, digital-communications

I have my STM32F407 discovery board (master) interfaced with an MPU6050 sensor (slave) via an I2C interface, and it reads and writes data to it.

My questions is, what mode of operation is the stm32 board in ? It reads as well as writes to the sensor. So is it in Master Transmitter when it is writing to it, and in Master Receiver mode when it reads data from it?

Answer (score 0):

In i2c the master controls both the write and read operations. The slave cannot send data unsolicited. The master provides the read frame and the slave adds the data to it.

Note that a read operation doesn't tell the slave device what to send. It's just says "send me a byte". As a result, most devices use a protocol where you first use a write operation to send a register address to the slave, then use a read operation to retrieve the data.

This isn't required by the i2c protocol. It's just a method that's commonly used by device manufacturers.

Comment: Actually the read without first sending what to read is used in some chips to some default data, like sensor data, to save bandwidth. And of course a slave only device can't start a transmission so devices that act as slaves but are able to start tranmisions are both slaves and masters in a multi-master design.